# ParameterValue for ParameterKey Content required

Tags: validation, parameters, ansible, aws-cloudformation

```
"msg": "Failed to create stack lambda-layer-test5: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: ParameterValue for ParameterKey Content is required
```

My vars are being past correctly according to `debug`:

```yaml
- name: Debug task to show CloudFormation parameters
  debug:
    msg: "lambda layer: {{ item.0.name }}-{{ item.1 }}-layer"
  loop: "{{ lambda_runtimes | subelements('layers') }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'python310', 'layers': ['requests']}, 'requests']) => {
    "msg": "lambda layer: python310-requests-layer"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'python311', 'layers': ['urllib3', 'requests']}, 'urllib3']) => {
    "msg": "lambda layer: python311-urllib3-layer"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'python311', 'layers': ['urllib3', 'requests']}, 'requests']) => {
    "msg": "lambda layer: python311-requests-layer"
```

as expected, but the error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: ParameterValue for ParameterKey Content is required
failed: [localhost] (item=[{'name': 'python310', 'layers': ['requests']}, 'requests']) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "boto3_version": "1.34.32",
    "botocore_version": "1.34.32",
    "changed": false,
    "error": {
        "code": "ValidationError",
        "message": "ParameterValue for ParameterKey Content is required",
        "type": "Sender"
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "access_key": null,
            "aws_ca_bundle": null,
            "aws_config": null,
            "backoff_delay": 3,
            "backoff_max_delay": 30,
            "backoff_retries": 10,
            "capabilities": [
                "CAPABILITY_IAM",
                "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
            ],
            "changeset_name": null,
            "create_changeset": false,
            "create_timeout": null,
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
            "disable_rollback": true,
            "endpoint_url": null,
            "events_limit": 200,
            "notification_arns": null,
            "on_create_failure": null,
            "profile": "twe",
            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "role_arn": null,
            "secret_key": null,
            "session_token": null,
            "stack_name": "lambda-layer-test5",
            "stack_policy": null,
            "stack_policy_body": null,
            "stack_policy_on_update_body": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "Dev",
                "Stack": "stack_name"
            },
            "template": "files/lambda_layer.yml",
            "template_body": null,
            "template_parameters": {
                "Content": {
                    "S3Bucket": "twe-enc-common-test-lambdalayer-org",
                    "S3Key": "python310-requests-layer.zip"
                },
                "LayerName": "requests",
                "Runtime": "python310"
            },
            "template_url": null,
            "termination_protection": null,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "layers": [
                "requests"
            ],
            "name": "python310"
        },
        "requests"
    ],
```

Can't find ANY information on this at all, can anyone help? please?

that is above:

- i have tried hardcoding
- tried deployemnt via awscli
- tried to create stack manually

ALL THE ABOVE WORKS, BUT when i pass those vars dynamically into cfn template, keeps saying NO content passed, very stumped.

all help fully appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please pay attention to the code formatting and create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~ so that other community members could read and understand the question easier. This time I fixed the formatting for you - you can accept the edit to shorten the moderation queue. After that, please add the failing playbook code to the question. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided the task which report this error. Can you add it? Best together with your playbook?